# show that list of polynomials is not linearly independent

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose that $p_0, p_1, ... p_m$ are polynomials in $P_m\mathbb(F)$ such that $P_j(2) = 0$ for each $j$. Prove that $(p_0, ... p_m)$ is linearly dependent.

Work so far:

Assume that it is. Then it is a basis for $P_m$. Now, I need help.

After looking around, most solutions mention that every polynomial of degree $\leq m$ can be written with list $p_0, p_1, ... p_m$ (under the assumption that it is a basis. It's not, I know.) I do not understand this restriction to $\leq m$. Why do we need this restriction?

Second, most solutions use a reduction. It goes something like let $p(x) \in span(p_0(x) + \ldots + p_m(x))$. But let $x =2$. Then $p(x) = 2$. But how is this a contradiction. Yes, when $x = 2$, then $p(x) = 0$. What does this contradict with?

Here is a solution: http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~asdugas/108A_SP08/108Ahw3sol.pdf
(problem 12)

When it says "$p(2) = 0$ for any polynomial of $p(x)$ of degree less or equal to $m$. Contradiction." This doesn't make sense. What are we contradicting?

Comment: If the basis polynomials all have a root at $2$, how will any linear combination represent a polynomial which does not have that root?

Comment: I added a bit. As much sense as that makes, it doesn't help me interpret other people's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $p(x) = x$. Then $p(2) = 2$. Can this particular polynomial be a linear combination of polynomials which all take the value $0$ at $2$? If not, then you have $m+1$ polynomials which do not span the vector space, and the vector space has dimension $m+1$. Could the polynomials be linearly independent in this case? This is basically arguing the equivalent contrapositive of the argument you listed.  The argument listed says that if the $m+1$ polynomials are linearly independent, then they form a basis, so then all polynomials of degree $\leq m$ are linear combinations of the basis, and thus must satisfy $p(2) = 0$. So any polynomial of degree $\leq m$ which does not satisfy $p(2) = 0$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: First two sentences don't make sense. If p(x) = x, then p(2) =2. What is the line of thought there?

Comment: It's just a polynomial, any polynomial, of degree $\leq m$, which does not satisfy $p(2) = 0$.

Comment: Okay. But what does "this" refer to in your second sentence?

Comment: the polynomial $p(x) = x$. =)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the paper, it seems you may have a couple typos:

P_m(f) should be P_m(F) (is this saying F is the variable?)

P_j(2) should be p_j(2)

If the p_j were linearly independent, then every polynomial of degree <=m+1 should be a linear combination of the p_j.  Since p_j(2)=0 for every j, every linear combination p(f)=\sum_j a_jp_j(f), with a_j coefficients, has p(2)=0 (just plug in 2 and see).  But there exist (possibly infinite depending on the coefficients) polynomials q(f) of degree <=m+1 with q(2)\neq 0.  So the p_j can't be a basis.  (How can you write this q as a linear combination of the p_j?)

Comment: I can't read this.